# Redshift combine two queries

Tags: amazon-redshift

Consider the following queries to get counts:

Query A

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    "user_notifications"
WHERE
    "user_notifications"."source_id" = 5196
    AND "user_notifications"."source_type" = 'MassGifting'
    AND "user_notifications"."status" = 'sent'
    AND "user_notifications"."read_at" IS NULL
```

Executation details:
[image: Redshift Pannel]
This takes about 6-10seconds.

Query B
Its also on the same table, just where clause is slightly different, trying to check sounds of notifications based on their status, if they have been read based on source_id & source_type.:

```
    SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    "user_notifications"
WHERE
    "user_notifications"."source_id" = 5196
    AND "user_notifications"."source_type" = 'MassGifting'
    AND (
        "user_notifications"."read_at" IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Execution Details:
[image]
Time taken: 5-6seconds. In total is takes about 30-60seconds to execute these two queries & render the report on our website.

I was wondering what are the way which we can speed this up?

Comment: How much data do you have in your user_notifications table? Do you have any sort key or dist key? Without sort key in where condition, it is quite difficult to speed up.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, and let me know how much time does it take? 
It should give you the result for both the queries in 1 table scan.

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when        
    "user_notifications"."status" = 'sent'
    AND "user_notifications"."read_at" IS NULL
    then 1 else 0 end) as Result1,
    SUM(case when        
    "user_notifications"."read_at" IS NOT NULL
    then 1 else 0 end) as Result2,
FROM
    "user_notifications"
WHERE
    "user_notifications"."source_id" = 5196
    AND "user_notifications"."source_type" = 'MassGifting'
```

If I’ve made a bad assumption please comment and I’ll refocus my answer.